# Get the CORRECT size of an UIWebView after it has loaded, swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uiwebview

I am having so much trouble showing a simple vimeo videon on my UIWebView. I have come so far that i can show the video and it is able to play in fullscreen mode.

The problem is that the video is not fitting properly inside my UIWebView.

In storyboard the UIWebView is set to have 560 in width and 105 in height. This is obviously changed in runtime since it resizes to fit different screens.

This becomes a problem because in the html embedded code that is needed to show the video is where you specify the videos size such as width and height.

So now for my question.. How can i get the correct size of my UIWebView after it has been loaded and all so i can match it with the videos frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your web view fills the whole view you can get the views frame and get the width and height from there.

Call this code in viewDidAppear():

```
let height = view.frame.height
let width = view.frame.width
```

Comment: So much i know to, But that gives me the values that are stored in the storyboard which is 560 and 105. But actually in runtime the view has 350 and 133

Comment: Do you get the size in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear?

Comment: That worked just fine thank you. Changed it to viewDidAppear love you. Just change your answer to put it in viewDidAppear and ill accept the answer

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you.